# Odd flickering after video driver update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, video

I'm not sure how to describe this other than to show you guys. I captured a video and uploaded it to YouTube here: http://youtu.be/Bp25Fyy_GsI

Notice how the tab selection keeps changing by itself without me selecting anything with the mouse or keyboard. Also hovering over different parts of the window will change the tab selection and the display.

This happens in Firefox as well, so it is not limited to that one application. In Firefox the page would constantly scroll up and down really quickly and look really "jerky." This started happening after I updated my video card driver for my GTX 560 Ti from 331.38 to 340.32 using the xorg-edgers PPA.

I did the update by performing a `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-331` followed by all of the other nvidia packages. After which I performed a restart and installed the `nvidia-340` package. Did I break something in the process? How do I fix it?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT** Using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with Nvidia GTX 560 Ti.

Answer (score 9):

I think I found the fix. Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1314367/comments/22

so far so good. I'll update this if it starts flickering again.

For those that are wondering, you need to install compizconfig-settings-manager first from terminal. `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Open it and go to workarounds and then place a check on `Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint`. DO NOT MESS WITH ANYTHING ELSE! No restart necessary (at least for me).

Comment: Worked for me:)