# Flickering screen appears while starting lenovo G580 laptop with ubuntu 15.10

Tags: startup, login-screen, flicker

I have recently installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo G580 20157. During the installation an error message showed up and the screen flickered. But when I pressed the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key the flickering stopped and Ubuntu installed successfully. Now, during boot, when the Ubuntu logo is displayed the screen flickers and the screen shifts between a terminal screen and the login screen. But pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> again helps to login. Apart from this there are no further issues in Ubuntu 15.10. I'm using intel i5 processor and no graphics card installed.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLxlg9a9Lzk&feature=youtu.be

*Can anyone help me to resolve the flickering screen bug?*

Comment: What graphics card are you using?? If it's Nvidia you should try to switch your drivers to a different version. Try following this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/623367/ubuntu-15-04-flashes-log-in-screen-then-black (I know it's for 15.04)

Comment: or try http://askubuntu.com/questions/263996/fixing-the-nvidia-graphics-screen-flicker-issue

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/692679/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Comment: I'm using intel core i5 processor not put any graphics card